# Basic Authentication with SpringXDTemplate

Tags: rest, basic-authentication, spring-xd

The [SpringXDTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/xd/rest/client/impl/SpringXDTemplate.html) is the SpringXD [java client](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#JAVA-API). Build around the [REST API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#REST-API) it doesn't support **Basic Authentication** required by the same API:

> the REST endpoints will require Basic authentication for access;

Furthermore the RestTemplate used undernet is not accessible cutting the possibility to implement the Basic Auth at lower level.

Perhaps i'm missing something? Advices are suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this API but looking at javadocs, I see a constructor of template that accepts ClientHttpRequestFactory. So maybe if you try to pass your own implementation that will append HTTP Authorization header with basic authentication when createRequest is invoked, that may solve your problem. Otherwise I don't see other way how to "get into" the process of template.